# Modal popup outside browser viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup on my website for some registration.
When this popup opens on a phone, it is to high for the browser view port, and some of the content comes outside it.

[image: illustration of the problem]

When I try to scroll down, it scroll the background. If I lock the background with `overflow-y: hidden`, nothing scrolls at all.

The popup scrolls with the window, locked at the same place.
I would like to not lock the position to the top of the page, and have it always appear in the top of the view port, but it should be possible to scroll to see all its contents.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: We might need a bit of code to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `media` types to write CSS rules for mobile devices, tablets, etc. for example if you want the ability of scroll in you modal content you can do something like:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .modal-content { overflow-y: scroll; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Bootstrap modal manager](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/) large example. They remove the overflow in the body (overflow:hidden) and have a full width/height wrapper for the modal, this wrapper has overflow:auto; and this makes the apparance than the body page is static and the page-scroll move only the modal.

Answer (score 0):

This will display a vertical scrollbar if the container exceeds the viewport height:

```
.some-modal {
    maxHeight: 100vh;
    overflowY: 'auto';
    overscrollBehavior: 'contain'; /* <-- nice to have but not required */
}
```